# Extract dirname from full path stored in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-like, dirname

How to extract only the dirname from full path which was stored in database.

I need to insert the scan files in another table which will filter only by dirname.

> ex.
>
> 1. /mnt/HD/HD_a2/Watch Me.mp3
> 2. /mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic/sample.mp3
>
>    - full path stored in tbl_files

`INSERT INTO tbl_transcode (file_id) 
Select file_id from tbl_files where UPPER(file_path) Like CONCAT((Select source_path from tbl_transcode_folder where trancode_folder_id = 1 ),'%') and media_type = 'video'`

But I need only dirname to insert in `tbl_transcode`, I think `LIKE` is not good to use.

Ex. I want to search only the dirname of this `/mnt/HD/HD_a2/Watch Me.mp3` but when I used like `/mnt/HD/HD_a2%` it return me like this. which shown also other dirname.

> 1. /mnt/HD/HD_a2/Watch Me.mp3
> 2. /mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic/sample.mp3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you are collecting the directory names for each file not the full path to the directory of the file.

Following answer is specific to Oracle, where we make use of `regexp_substr` method.

> To get the full path with directory name we can use the following
>   regular expression:

```
substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(c1,'^(.*/)*'),0,instr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(c1,'^(.*/)*'),'/',-1)-1)
```

> To get only the directory name we can use the following regular
>   expression:

```
replace(regexp_substr(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(c1,'^(.*/)*'),0,instr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(c1,'^(.*/)*'),'/',-1)-1),'/[a-zA-Z_0-9]+$'),'/','')
```

Here `c1` is a sample column i have used at my end.

So, your updated query will be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_transcode (file_id) 
Select file_id from tbl_files where UPPER(file_path) = upper(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(source_path,'^(.*/)*'),0,instr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(source_path,'^(.*/)*'),'/',-1)-1)) and media_type = 'video';
```

You can also check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de839/2) sqlfiddle

**Update (Answer specific to MySQL):**

We can make use of `substring_index`, `locate` & `substring` methods from MySQL to achieve the extraction of dir name.

The `substring_index` method returns the substring from the number of occurrence of a character. Here the character of interest is `/`. So, invoking `substring_index(c1,'/',-1)` returns the file names from the given dir path.

Next we can use `locate` to find the index of position of the file name and get the substring till beginning of file name using `substr`.

> To get the file names:

`SELECT substring_index(c1,'/',-1) FROM t1;`

> To get the directory name with full path:

`SELECT substring(c1,1,locate(substring_index(c1,'/',-1),c1)-1) FROM t1;`

> To get only the directory name:

`SELECT substring_index(substring(c1,1,locate(substring_index(c1,'/',-1),c1)-2),'/',-1) FROM t1;`

So, in the updated query for your case will be like the following:

`INSERT INTO tbl_transcode (file_id) 
    Select file_id from tbl_files where UPPER(file_path) = upper(substring_index(substring(source_path,1,locate(substring_index(source_path,'/',-1),source_path)-2),'/',-1)) and media_type = 'video';`

Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddff1/16) fiddle for a working example

Comment: I actually using sql queries, any difference syntax when it use in orale? I tried it but nothings good happen, return me an error `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'instr' ` What i want is like this i have a database column which stored full path like this `/mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic/sample.mp3` but i need only to get its dirname not including the basename like this `/mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic`.

Comment: @Amboom Are you using MySQL? Syntax for certain SQL queries & methods change between databases.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_path, '.*/.*?')
```

I felt this may work and just tried. I thought I know why but when I started explaining I realized that there is no reason.

Comment: Asking a question in an answer post is not acceptable. Providing something which works and admitting to be unable to explain is ... honest, my respect. But maybe you better use your commenting privilege on this. And even that might get removed as "not needed anymore".... This could however make an interesting separate question post. The more according to [ask] the better the chances for appreciative feedback.